# Are there smooth functions that in their limit can perform ceiling and floor operations?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

#### Preamble

1. There is a motivation section at the bottom which explains where this arose from -- might be helpful or of interest
2. There is a set of ideal criteria which if met would define the ideal solution
3. There a follow on set of less than criteria which relax the ideal criteria -- some readers pointed out that the original criteria are unnecessarily restrictive

Do we have

#### Ideal Criteria

$1.$ functions like $f(x,\theta)$ and $g(x,\theta)$

$2.$ are defined where $\theta \in {\rm I\!R}^1$ and $x \in {\rm I\!R}^1$

$3.$ are **smooth** and **continuous** where $ \left| \theta \right| \lt C$ where $C$ is some constant

$4.$ $f$ and $g$ themselves cannot be defined (make use of) the floor or ceiling functions

$5.$ $f$ and $g$ cannot be defined as different functions over subsets over their domain for example: (,)=0 for ||< and (,)=⌊⌋

$6.$ $f$ and $g$ can make use of $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ operators

$7.$ $f$ and $g$ can make use of frequency type decomposition

#### Less than Ideal Criteria -- which may involve relaxing some of the Ideal Criteria

$8.$ a less than ideal solution would allow $\theta$ to be $\in \mathbb{Z}$

$9.$ a less than ideal solution can allow $f$ and $g$ to make of differentiation and integration

$10.$ a borderline admissible solution would allow $f$ and $g$ to a composition of different functions over disjoint subsets over their domain -- in other word relaxing condition $4.$

that we get

$$
\lim_{\theta \to \infty} f(x, \theta) = \lfloor x \rfloor
$$

and

$$
\lim_{\theta \to \infty} g(x, \theta) = \lceil x \rceil
$$

#### Motivation

1. The question really comes from can we implement something in terms of something else -- kinda like how can we use deterministic logic to generate random numbers, or how can we implement a Turing machine using NAND logic
2. Additionally, more mental itch -- would be great to see floor and ceiling implementations using middle-school or say high-school math
3. I want a representation off floor and ceiling that is does not make use of the if-then -- say we were to implement floor and ceiling in terms of electrical or mechanical machinery, if-then machinery is complex and expensive
4. Say we were in a world where analog computers existed where we had black-boxes that did addition, multiplication, power, division, log, but no memory and no if-then/jump type stuff -- could we implement floor and ceiling
5. Allowing direct memory components such as accumulators or delay operators would not be allowed

Comment: You cannot take the limit $\theta\to\infty$ if $f$ is defined only for $|\theta|<C$.

Comment: Opps let me correct

Comment: @GReyes -- hope my edits fix the issue you pointed out -- thanks

Comment: It only has to be smooth for $|\theta| < C$? In that case why not just let $f(x, \theta) = 0$ for $|\theta| < C$ and $f(x, \theta) = \lfloor x \rfloor$ otherwise?  Since you only care about the limit as $\theta \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @JairTaylor, fair point -- I don't know how to specify this condition but we cannot have the function defined as different functions over disjoined domains -- I'll try to add this criteria of the question

Comment: Can it be defined in terms of $\cot^{-1}(\cot(\pi x)) / \pi$ (which equals $\lfloor x \rfloor$)? What specifically about the greatest integer function are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @aschepler -- I think that may be it -- let me process

Comment: Wait, that's $\{x\}$. Plus it fails for $n \pi$. So $x - \cos^{-1}(\cos(\pi x)) / \pi$, maybe.

Comment: No, still not quite.

Comment: Is there any reason for conditions 4 and 5 other than to make things unreasonably difficult?

Comment: @DavidK great point -- let me tone down the question a bit and kind-of explain my motivation

Comment: @DavidK -- Edited the question to allow some relaxation of 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of building these functions.

Throughout most of this, I'll be discussing functions with a domain where $\theta > 0$. But at the end, there's a way to fix that up if desired.

First, to get a non-smooth "sharpness", approximate $|x|$ by hyperbolae with $y=\pm x$ as asymptotes:

$$ f_1(x,\theta) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{\theta}} $$
$$ \lim_{\theta \to \infty} f_1(x,\theta) = |x| $$

The derivative of this function with respect to $x$ will have a discontinuity in the $\theta \to \infty$ limit, without explicitly being defined with an "if-else", and remaining smooth at all $\theta>0$:

$$ f_2(x,\theta) = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x,\theta) = x \left(x^2 + \frac{1}{\theta}\right)^{-1/2} $$
$$ \lim_{\theta \to \infty} f_2(x,\theta) = \begin{cases}
-1 & x<0 \\
0 & x=0 \\
1 & x>0 \end{cases} $$

Also notice that $|f_2(x,\theta)| < 1$ for all real $x$ and all positive $\theta$.

The "fractional part" function $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is periodic, so to work in some periodicity the natural choice is trigonometric functions. One slight catch is that we need the function to be one-to-one on the period between discontinuities, but $\sin$ and $\cos$ are not one-to-one in their periods. But this use of $f_2$ solves that nicely by using half-periods of the trig functions:

$$ f_3(x,\theta) = \cos(\pi x) \, f_2 \big(\!\sin(\pi x), \theta \big) $$
$$ \lim_{\theta \to \infty} f_3(x,\theta) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\cos\!\big[\pi (x- \lfloor x \rfloor) \big] & x \notin \mathbb{Z} \end{cases} $$

(If $2n < x < 2n+1$ for some integer $n$, then $\cos(\pi x) = \cos\!\big[\pi(x - 2n) + 2n \pi\big] = \cos\!\big[\pi(x - \lfloor x \rfloor)\big]$, and $f_2$ approaches $+1$ in the limit. If $2n+1 < x < 2n+2$, then $\cos(\pi x) = \cos\!\big[\pi(x - 2n-1) + (2n+1)\pi\big] = -\cos\!\big[\pi(x - \lfloor x \rfloor)\big]$, and $f_2$ approaches $-1$ in the limit.)

Since $|\cos| \leq 1$ and $|f_2| < 1$, $|f_3(x,\theta)| < 1$ on the domain, which means the arccosine is defined. So the next simple step:

$$ f_4(x,\theta) = x - \frac{1}{\pi}\, \cos^{-1}\! \big[ f_3(x,\theta) \big] $$
$$ \lim_{\theta \to \infty} f_4(x,\theta) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} & x \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\lfloor x \rfloor & x \notin \mathbb{Z} \end{cases} $$

[@GregMartin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16078/greg-martin) mentioned in a comment a way to fix up singleton points, like these at the discontinuities:

$$ f_5(x,\theta) = (\cos^2 \pi x)^\theta $$
$$ \lim_{\theta \to \infty} f_5(x,\theta) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in \mathbb{Z} \\
0 & x \notin \mathbb{Z} \end{cases} $$
$$ f_6(x,\theta) = f_4(x,\theta) + \frac{1}{2} f_5(x,\theta) $$
$$ \lim_{\theta \to \infty} f_6(x,\theta) = \lfloor x \rfloor $$

Or written all the way out,

$$ f_6(x,\theta) =  x - \frac{1}{\pi} \cos^{-1} \left[
\cos(\pi x) \sin(\pi x) \left(\sin^2(\pi x) + \frac{1}{\theta}\right)^{-1/2}
\right]
+ \frac{1}{2} (\cos^2 \pi x)^\theta $$

This function is smooth everywhere, but its limit at large $\theta$ is not. See a graph of $f_6(x,5)$ [on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20x%20-%201%2Fpi%20*%20arccos%28cos%28pi%20x%29%20sin%28pi%20x%29%20%28%28sin%28pi%20x%29%29%5E2%20%2B%201%2F5%29%5E%28-1%2F2%29%29%20%2B%201%2F2%28cos%28pi%20x%29%29%5E10).

If definition on all real $\theta$ is important, instead of just on positive $\theta$, you could take $f_7(x,\theta) = f_6(x,e^\theta)$.

Since $\lceil x \rceil = - \lfloor -x \rfloor$, a similar function approaching $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is just

$$ g(x,\theta) = -f_6(-x,\theta) $$

[or use $f_7$ in place of $f_6$.]

Answer (score 2):

For continuous functions, we can take
$$
f(x,\theta) = \lfloor x \rfloor + \big( x - \lfloor x \rfloor \big)^\theta.
$$
It's easy to convert this to smooth functions, since there is always a smooth function $\tilde f(x,\theta)$ uniformly satisfying $\big| \tilde f(x,\theta) - f(x,\theta) \big| < \frac1\theta$.

In any case, we can take $g(x,\theta) = -f(-x,\theta)$, since $-\lfloor-x\rfloor = \lceil x\rceil$.

Comment: great answer -- what I missed I think was that f and g should not make use of the floor or ceiling functions

Comment: I added a fourth criteria that $f$ and $g$ cannot be defined in terms of floor and ceiling functions

Comment: I'm sure that's possible, but it's going to be harder because most natural discontinuous functions that arise as limits of sequences of continuous functions have values at the discontinuity that is the average of the one-sided limits, which is not the case for the floor and ceiling functions.

Comment: That is the case, in particular, if you approximate the mantissa (which is periodic) by its Fourier series (which formally would not contain the floor or ceiling function explicitly). I do not see any simple solution..

Comment: @GregMartin -- yes my intuition was some sort of Fourier-esq based solution -- but I'm pretty lapsed mathematically and this curious

Comment: Oh, I suppose one could combine the Fourier series of $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ with something like a multiple of $(\cos^2 \pi x)^\theta$, which in the limit would have the effect of changing the values at the discontinuities.